# Unable to pass object to another Android activity(with parcelable)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

//ListSalesItemActivity (this is an activity with listview and when I click one item listed, I will go to ViewDetailActivity with datas shown)

I was able to get data, but not able to pass to another acticity and application will stop

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_sale_item);

    myContext = this;


    salesLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.salesLV);


    salesLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListSaleItemActivity.this, SaleDetailActivity.class);

            SaleObject SO = mc.SalesObjectList(getApplicationContext()).get(position);
            Log.d("myTag", SO.getStrName());//able to get name
            bundle.putString("Name", SO.getStrName());
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    });

}
```

//ViewDetailActivity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale_detail);
    {

        Bundle bd = i.getExtras();
        String name = bd.getString("Name");
        Log.d("myTag", name);//does not print anything in logcat and application stopped.

        //I tried this and also does not work
        /*if(bd != null)
        {
            String getName = (String) bd.get("Name");
            Log.d("myTag", getName);
        }else{
            Log.d("myTag", "1");
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: it is easy to find out the error before go through the coding if you have post the log(error report)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put i = getIntent(); inside onCreate().

```
Intent i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale_detail);
{

    i = getIntent();
    Bundle bd = i.getExtras();
    String name = bd.getString("Name");
    Log.d("myTag", name);

}
```

}